# + 1 to new sheet names

Tags: vba, excel

Please can you provide code to + 1 to any new sheet name assuming that the sheet will be called pivot.

So lets say we have a sheet called pivot, I want the next sheet to be pivot 1 and the sheet after to be pivot 2.

Comment: Opps ... wrong website.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro, and doing it manually to see what the code might look like ? 9 times out of 10, in Excel, this is the easy way to answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding a new sheet every time? If so, try this:

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet 'Adds a new sheet
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = Pivot1

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = Pivot2
```

Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Hi, I want the process to be automated so that code count the number of sheets with pivot and adds 1 to the sheet name.

Comment: You cannot have multiple sheets with the same name in the first place... You seem to be implying that you have, for example, 3 sheets named "Pivot" (which is not possible) and would like to rename these sheets to Pivot1, Pivot2, etc. Maybe I'm not understanding what you're getting at.